# Rails each_with_index descend order in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9. When we code `@objects.each_with_index do |object, i|`, `i` usually starts with `0`, `1`, `2`. etc.

Let's say we have `@objects = [A, B, C, D, E]`, and the output is:

```
<% @objects.each_with_index do |object, i| %>
  <%= i %> - <%= object %><br>
<% end %>

# output
0 - A
1 - B
2 - C
```

I wanna have this instead:

```
# output
2 - A
1 - B
0 - C
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<%= @objects.length - 1 - i %> - <%= object %><br>`

this will substract the index of the length of the array, giving the desired output.

You have to always substract one from the length since a array with length 3 has indexes 0, 1, 2

Answer (score 1):

How is this?

```
a = [:a,:b,:c]
a.each.with_index(-a.length+1) {|e,i| print -i,"  ",e,"\n"}
```

**output:**

```
2  a
1  b
0  c
```

Your one could be something like that:

```
<% @objects.each.with_index(-@objects.length+1) do |object, i| %>
  <%= -i %> - <%= object %><br>
<% end %>
```